# Server communicate back to multiple different clients

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, ip

So I got as an assignment to make a small chat function where multiple clients should be able to connect to a server and communicate with it, the server should then be able to choose whom it wants to communicate back with. (From a dropdown list or something).

What I've been able to do so far, with help from some tutorials, is that clients can connect to the server and communicate with it but nothing more. The server can't communicate back.

I'm very new to this and have limited knowledge in both C# and TCP/IP.

https://gist.github.com/4565988 <-Contains both code for client and server.

So I what I need help with is a way for the server to reply to different clients and for the client to recieve a message from the server.

Any help is appreciated!

Best Regards, Fredrik

Comment: How did you manage to open a TCP connection that is only one way? TCP always goes both ways per definition.

Comment: Well I guess the problem isn't that it's not opened just one way but rather that I don't know how to communicate back.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to a starting point, I would have a look at [WCF Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx). Duplex allow you to subscribe to the service and send updates out using two-way communication.

Essentially you can create the server as a WCF service with a couple of methods: `getclients` and `sendMessage`. From there, a client can then subscribe to the service and (while connected) get a list of other subscribers (which you provide to the UI) and then send a message back to the service (which will then use duplexing to send it to whomever it needs to).

As long as you're not married to using sockets, this would be a lot easier than creating a protocol and managing a list of connections. There are also examples of using WCF as a chat medium available on [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19752/WCF-WPF-Chat-Application).

Answer (score 0):

For TCP knowledge I reconn Barbara Heckler's vid where she shows a brief implementation of such kind of server. Unfortunately in Java, but nevertheless very useful.

I reconn minute 0 - 15 for the basics (UDP) and 15 - 40 for the TCP connection and why mutlithreading is need for TCP but not for UDP.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QzNHEcLp10

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, really. That TCP stream you successfully extract and use to read what the client(s) sent can also be written to in order to send back something, so all you  have to do is move the connection and stream objects out to shared collections of some sort so that your server-side sending logic can get at it when it wants to send something. Similarly, in the client you would issue a read on the TCP stream to read what the server sent.